# How to detect and tabulate data from an excel file?

Tags: python, r, text-mining, non-relational-database

I have an Excel file (Available at [Google Drive](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c8bSje2wP9fffaoOSDAMYO34RwKff3os/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=110947871950285579478&rtpof=true&sd=true)) with data which was saved with a very strange format in order to get printed easily:

[image: Non-relational data, available at Google Drive]

And every table repeats daily for over 5 years. I need to analyze this data and tried to get a relational format in order to load it in R/Python-like tools and get only 5 columns:

| DATE | CLIENT NAME | TEST | MEASUREMENT | TESTER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2023 | JOHN SMITH | METABOLYTE A | 0.01 | PhD. IMA GU |
| 01-01-2023 | JOHN SMITH | METABOLYTE B | 10 | PhD. IMA GU |
| 01-01-2023 | JOHN SMITH | PCR | NEGATIVE | PhD. IMA GU |
| 01-01-2023 | JOHN SMITH | MUTATION | +++ | PhD. IMA GU |
| 01-01-2023 | ALBUS DUMBLE | PREGNANT | NEGATIVE | TECH. GUIVER |
| 01-01-2023 | ALBUS DUMBLE | GLUCOSE | 121 | TECH. GUIVER |
| 02-01-2023 | MAYDAY JUNE | METABOLYTE A | 0.01 | PhD. IMA GU |
| 02-01-2023 | JOHN SMITH | METABOLYTE A | 0.01 | TECH. GUIVER |
| 02-01-2023 | JOHN SMITH | METABOLYTE B | 10 | TECH. GUIVER |
| 02-01-2023 | JOHN SMITH | PCR | NEGATIVE | TECH. GUIVER |
| 02-01-2023 | JOHN SMITH | MUTATION | +++ | TECH. GUIVER |

So, in order to get a conversion from non-relational data to relational table I have applied text-mining techniques available at this [GitHub](https://github.com/silvertaqman/kunu-kutu-data/tree/master) repo. But, basically, have converted everything into one column with `tidyr::pivot_longer()`. Is there any optimal function or method to detect and tabulate this kind of data, or should i try to do it with a loop (+843 files)?

Comment: Can you share a copy of the sheet (or just a small sample of it?) Either as a csv or on Google Sheets? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you could use awk and regex, the syntax is very cryptic but its super fast and capable.

Comment: Done, data shared as a Google sheet file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My attempt is based on fact, that the entries are formatted identically, so we can use kind of 'moving window'.

```r
a <- openxlsx::read.xlsx(xlsxFile = "/home/sapi/Downloads/ENERO_2023_prueba.xlsx",
                    colNames = FALSE
                    )
```

Now we have to define data frame for data storage. Comments like `# [2,2] +0, +1` corresponds to row and column of `a` (loaded excel).

```r
entry <- data.frame(
  NOMBRE = character(),    # [2,2] +0, +1
  FECHA = character(),     # [2,6] +0, +5
  MUESTRA = character(),   # [3,3] +1, +2
  place = character(),     # [3,5] +1, +4
  COLOR = character(),     # [6,3] +4, +2
  ASPECTO = character(),   # [7,3] +5< +2
  DENSIDAD = double(),     # [8,3] +6, +2
  PH = character(),        # [9,3] +7, +2
# ...
  LEUCOCITOS = character(),#[19,3] +17, +2
  BACTERIAS = character(), # [6,7] +4, +6
  PIOCITOS = character()   # [7,7] +5, +6
# ...
)
```

Now we have to find all rows with `NOMBRE`

```r
nombre_rows <- which(a[,"X1"] == "NOMBRE")
```

and use it in loop like:

```r
for (i in 1:length(nombre_rows)) {
  x <- nombre_rows[i]
  nombre_cols <- which(a[x,] == "NOMBRE") # the same for columns
  for (j in 1:length(nombre_cols)) {
    y <- nombre_cols[j]

    entry <- data.frame(
      NOMBRE = a[x, y+1],
      FECHA = a[x, y+5],
      MUESTRA = a[x+1, y+2],
      place = a[x+1, y+4],
      COLOR = a[x+4, y+2],
      ASPECTO = a[x+5, y+2],
      DENSIDAD = a[x+6, y+2],
      PH = a[x+7, y+2],
      # ...
      LEUCOCITOS = a[x+17, y+2],
      BACTERIAS = a[x+4, y+6],
      PIOCITOS = a[x+5, y+6]
      # ...
    ) |> rbind(entry)
  }
}
```

And finally the data:

```r
head(entry)
#>             NOMBRE   FECHA MUESTRA            place      COLOR      ASPECTO
#> 1      RUANO EDITH 44957.0   ORINA         CEXTERNA  AMARILLO   LIG.TURBIO 
#> 2    CUNIN ELVIRA  44957.0   ORINA HOSPÌTALIZACION   AMARILLO       TURBIO 
#> 3 LOACHAMIN MARIA  44957.0   ORINA         CEXTERNA  AMARILLO  TRANSPARENTE
#> 4    MANZANO RAUL  44957.0   ORINA         CEXTERNA  AMARILLO   LIG.TURBIO 
#> 5    MERCHAN IVAN  44957.0   ORINA      HIDRATACION ANARANJADO      TURBIO 
#> 6   ACERO ANTHONY  44957.0   ORINA         CEXTERNA   AMARILLO  LIG.TURBIO 
#>   DENSIDAD  PH LEUCOCITOS    BACTERIAS     PIOCITOS
#> 1   1005.0 8.0   NEGATIVO            +    1-2/CAMPO
#> 2   1020.0 5.0        +++           ++ CAMPO LLENO 
#> 3   1005.0 6.0   NEGATIVO OCASIONALES    1-2/CAMPO 
#> 4   1010.0 7.0   NEGATIVO            +   3-7/CAMPO 
#> 5   1015.0 6.0         ++           ++ 50-60/CAMPO 
#> 6   1010.0 5.0   NEGATIVO            +   0-2/CAMPO
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

You should extend the `entry` data frame to grab all variables from your data. And then loop it through all excels you have.

Comment: Even if all files doesn't have the same format of "moving window" this is ma excellent approach. Is easier to search for those and edit them. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for kind words, the most important it helped. And yes, adopt it to your excels/structures.